# Query to handle single quoted objects in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I was using a sql query in jdbc

```
SELECT COUNT (COST_CENTER) AS count FROM IMDB1_FINANCE_BUDGET where COST_CENTER='object name'
```

this is working fine but i have some test objects like  '0654603 ? SSG Accounting with a single quote in beginning now query will be

```
SELECT COUNT (COST_CENTER) AS count FROM IMDB1_FINANCE_BUDGET where COST_CENTER=''0654603 ? SSG '
```

now it is throwing exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

how to handle such type of objects

Comment: You could use [q-quote operator](http://spavicic.blogspot.in/2012/04/little-bit-about-oracle-quote-operator.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with single-quotations in such cases is to use [Quoting string literal technique](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/quoting-string-literal-technique-to-avoid-erros-due-to-single-quotation-marks-in-the-string/)

For example, **q'['SCOTT]'**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '''SCOTT' nm FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE nm = q'['SCOTT]';

NM
------
'SCOTT

SQL>
```

Of course, the traditional way to enclose it with single-quotes **'''SCOTT'** would still work -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '''SCOTT' nm FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE nm = '''SCOTT';

NM
------
'SCOTT

SQL>
```